# No way to pass to virtual machine this old scsi controller?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, scsi

I have sucessfully passed to vm pci-e and pci pure devices.
I want to pass a scsi controller to a vm

the controller is seen by the os

```
06:06.0 SCSI storage controller [0100]: BusLogic BT-946C (BA80C30) [MultiMaster 10] [104b:1040]
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: BusLogic
```

I detach the controller

```
virsh nodedev-detach pci_0000_06_06_0
```

I start the vm

```
qemu-system-i386 -boot a -fda boot_install.img -m 128 -no-fd-bootchk --enable-kvm -device pcnet,netdev=network0 -netdev tap,id=network0,ifname=tap1,script=no,downscript=no -device vfio-pci,host=06:06.0
```

and...

```
qemu-system-i386: -device vfio-pci,host=06:06.0: VFIO_MAP_DMA failed: Cannot allocate memory
qemu-system-i386: -device vfio-pci,host=06:06.0: VFIO_MAP_DMA failed: Cannot allocate memory
qemu-system-i386: -device vfio-pci,host=06:06.0: vfio 0000:06:06.0: failed to setup container for group 12: memory listener initialization failed: Region pc.ram: vfio_dma_map(0x7fadc1bccc00, 0x0, 0xa0000, 0x7fadb5200000) = -12 (Cannot allocate memory)
```

how to solve?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `udev` rules to change ownership of the devices you wish to passthrough to your user. To not get this memory error you also need to increase the memory limit your user is able to allocate.

I use Arch Linux, so these files might be on different locations on your distribution.

- Create the group `kvm` if not already present, and add it to your user's supplementary groups. You can also use your own user's group, if you don't intend to run the vm as another user.
- Udev rules:

  Create the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-vm.rules`

  ```
  SUBSYSTEM=="vfio", OWNER="root", GROUP="kvm"
  SUBSYSTEM=="***", ATTR{idVendor}=="***", ATTR{idProduct}=="***" OWNER="root", GROUP="kvm"
  ```

  Edit the second line and add similar ones for every device you wish to passthrough with `vfio`, in this example I use the vendor and product IDs to match the device.
- Memory limit:

  Add the following lines to the file `/etc/security/limits.conf`

  ```
  @kvm     soft    memlock        150000
  @kvm     hard    memlock        150000
  ```

  Here we set the limit for the group `kvm` at 150000KB, that should be enough for your 128MB VM, but should be increased if you increase the VM's memory allocation.

**SOURCE:** https://www.evonide.com/non-root-gpu-passthrough-setup/ (the setup is a little different because he uses a separate user for the vm)

Answer (score 1):

Workaround found.
As root works, so was probably a permission problem